# Why is a Python exported file not closing?

Tags: python, python-3.x

When exporting a csv-file from Python, for some reason it does not close (even when using the 'with' statement) because when I'm calling it afterwards I get the following error:

```
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used 
by another process
```

I suppose it has to be the close function that hangs, because when I'm printing behind the `with` statement or the `close()` statement, it gets printed (e.g. `print fileName`). Any suggestions that might solve this matter?
(Also when I'm trying to open the exported CSV-file, I get a read-only message because it's used by another program. I can access it properly only when Python is closed, which is just annoying)

```
import csv, numpy, os
import DyMat
import subprocess

os.chdir("C:/Users/myvhove/Documents/ResultsPyDymInt/Dymola/CoupledClutches")


dm = DyMat.DyMatFile("dymatresfile")
print(dm.names())

varList = ('J1.w', 'J2.w', 'J3.w', 'J4.w')

fileName = dm.fileName + '.csv'
with open(fileName, 'w', newline='') as oFile:
    csvWriter = csv.writer(oFile)

    vDict = dm.sortByBlocks(varList)
    for vList in vDict.values():
        vData = dm.getVarArray(vList)
        vList.insert(0, dm._absc[0])
        csvWriter.writerow(vList)
        csvWriter.writerows(numpy.transpose(vData))


subprocess.call("dymatresfile.csv")

print(fileName)
```

Comment: You have another process (could it be an editor? or most likely another *Python* instance that failed, but it's still running), that's keeping the file open. You need to close / kill that 1st, before going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is correct. The problem must be somewhere else.

Either another forgotten python process or as @CristiFati mentioned an open editor.

In the worst case restart the PC and call the python script directly after logging in again.
The error should no more be there.

Comment: You were right. When trying to restart (with everything closed), my pc indicated something was still running in the background and nothing showed up in the Task Manager. Very weird. After restarting, the code working fine. Thanks!